# How to implement PayPal Express Checkout in PHP

Tags: php, curl, paypal

In addition to walking the user through the PayPal checkout process, I first need to do some DB work. Then I need to post 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr/ using cURL, but I receive an error:

> Bad Request. Your browser sent a request PayPal cannot understand.

I have added the following certificate to my shared server as instructed by the PayPal docs:

## COMODO ECC Certification Authority

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Here is the relevant PHP code:

```
function post2PayPal() {
    $url = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo 'pp=' . $response;
    exit();
}
post2PayPal();
```

What am i missing?

Comment: Mmmm someone can use your certificate now, cool

Comment: Is this a bad thing? It did not solve my problem.